# Subsetting data

Tags: r, subset

This is probably a very simple problem, but can't see what minor syntax error I have that's causing me to go wrong. I'm currently trying to subset my data so I get all data points that have a value above 0.75 for one column. So to demonstrate:-

```
head(res1)
          1           2           V1           V2
1 0.0000000  1.00000000         <NA>     (0.95,1]
2 0.1558227 -0.58209840 (0.15,0.175] (-0.6,-0.55]
3 1.0201810  0.14121170    (1,1.025]   (0.1,0.15]
4 1.1591957 -0.02665740 (1.15,1.175]    (-0.05,0]
5 1.9971474 -0.05425368    (1.975,2] (-0.1,-0.05]
6 2.0517603 -0.18734806 (2.05,2.075] (-0.2,-0.15]
```

`cut <- res1[ which(res1$2 > 0.75), ]`

When I do this I get the error:-

`Error: unexpected numeric constant in "cut <- res1[ which(res1$2"`

I know it's most likely a syntax error somewhere but I can't see where. Anyone able to help?

Comment: You can try `res1$'2'`

Comment: Bingo, thank you once agian akrun. Put it as an answer please?

Comment: It's okay.  There is already a community wiki answer posted.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  I think you can keep it as there is more info in that post.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using invalid names.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(`1` = 1:4, b = 5:8, check.names = FALSE)
df
#   1 b
# 1 1 5
# 2 2 6
# 3 3 7
# 4 4 8
```

Error:

```
df[which(df$1 > 2), ]
# Error: unexpected numeric constant in "df[which(df$1"
```

Solutions:

```
df[which(df$`1` > 2), ]
#   1 b
# 3 3 7
# 4 4 8

# or any of these (with single or double quotes):

df[which(df$"1"    > 2), ]
df[which(df[, "1"] > 2), ]
df[which(df[["1"]] > 2), ]
```

Documentation for all of these is found by typing `help("[")` or `` ?`[` ``.